# Unable to override spring boot's (default) security configuration

Tags: spring-security, spring-boot

I am trying to secure a Spring boot REST application using Spring security for basic authentication.

The default basic authentication works by simply plugging in the following dependency

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

The next step is to override the default authentication credentials provided by Spring boot with some custom credentials (username, password).

I have tried this using:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    @Autowired
    public void configure (AuthenticationManagerBuilder authBuilder) throws Exception {

        authBuilder.inMemoryAuthentication()
            .withUser("aide").password("aide").roles("USER").and()
            .withUser("pervacio").password("pervacio").roles("ADMIN");
    }

    @Override
    @Autowired
    protected void configure (HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.httpBasic().and()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/search").hasRole("ADMIN")
            .and().csrf().disable();
    }
}
```

Here is my Controller:

```
@RestController
@SpringBootApplication
public class Controller {

    // request mappings and other code here

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Controller.class, args);
    }
}
```

The problem that I am having is that I am unable to override the default credentials with custom ones.

How do I do this?

Other posts on SO suggest annotating the `configure` methods with `Autowired`, and that isn't working for me.

What am I doing wrong? I tried the above approach by following the [official example](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-examples/tree/master/rest/security).

Comment: what is the behavior you are getting? any exception or you cannot authenticate the user with your custom credentials?

Comment: @ChathurangaTennakoon thanks for asking. The default username (i.e. `user`) and default (randomly-generated) password are the ones that get authorized. My custom credentials defined in `SecurityConfiguration` above get a `401 Unauthorized (Bad Credentials)` response.

Comment: can you share the spring based login form? i need to loo at it? are you using a custom login form or spring security automatically generated login form ?

Comment: if this is a restful based service, how you are passing the login credentials? can i see that code as well?

Comment: I am exposing a REST interface, and using no login form (or views). I am sending the credentials as an HTTP header.

I am using a REST client (for Chrome) to test the REST api and setting the credentials as an HTTP header in this client.

Comment: what is the name of the parameter you are passing for the in memory authentication? is it username and password?

Comment: No, it isn't parameter based. As we are dealing with HTTP Basic authentication, we need to encode the credentials in the `Authorization` header.

Comment: @ChathurangaTennakoon I found the plausible cause of the problem. Please see my answer below. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The problem I realized was with the location (or package) of the `SecurityConfiguration`.

[`@ComponentScan`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/ComponentScan.html)  annotation (included as part of `@SpringBootApplication`) by default scans for components in the same package where it was defined.

Hence, there are two solutions: a) move the configuration to the same package where the annotation was defined b) configure the annotation to scan for components in the package where you placed your configuration

In my case, `SecurityConfiguration` file above was in a different package as compared with my application class.

**Solution a**:

Include the following annotation:

```
@ComponentScan({"<security-package-name>"})
```

and plug in the name of the package that has your security configuration.

**Solution b**:

Move the Java configuration class into the same package as that of the application class.